# Sonarqube API for sonarqube version 6.5

Tags: api, sonarqube

I have prepared a program for fetching sonarqube tool details using Sonarqube APIs.
I used following APIs:

1. I am using following api for fetching lines, ncloc, statements, files, classes, functions, accessors, commented lines, commented lines density, duplicated lines, duplicated lines density, violations, blocker violations, critical violations, major violations, minor violations,weighted violations, sqale index :

   "http://10.20.30.40:9000/sonar/api/timemachine?resource=project_key&metrics=lines,ncloc,statements,files,classes,functions,accessors,comment_lines,comment_lines_density,duplicated_lines,duplicated_lines_density,violations,blocker_violations,critical_violations,major_violations,minor_violations,weighted_violations,sqale_index"
2. Using another API for getting Creation date and last updated date :

   "http://10.20.30.40:9000/sonar/api/resources/index?metrics=date&format=json"
3. And for getting all project names and details, using below API:

   "http://10.20.30.40:9000/sonar/api/projects?format=json"

All these APIs are working fine for sonarqube version 4.3.
But same APIs are not working for sonarqube version 6.5

Could anyone help me to get utilization data from Sonarqube for all the version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API between SonarQube 4.3 (more than 3 years old) and SonarQube 6.5 are not compatible, you need to use the new API for SonarQube 6.5.

The easiest way to know available web services on your SonarQube instance is to go to http://your_sonarqube_instance/web_api.

Comment: ok.. so do you know where can I get new APIs? I googled but did not find it

Comment: You need to go to <SONARQUBE URL>/web_api. See for instance on SonarCloud (using 6.5) : https://sonarcloud.io/web_api

Comment: @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam : thanks, your answer helped me. If you could write separate answer, I will accept that one. :) thanks

Comment: Good news ! I've edited the answer as I've only give you hint on where to find the answer, it's not a new answer.